# HTML attributes escaping

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, encode

I'm reading the OWSAP prevention sheet, but I got confused with rule number 2.

> RULE #2 - Attribute Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Common Attributes
>   Rule #2 is for putting untrusted data into typical attribute values like width, name, value, etc. **This should not be used for complex attributes like href, src, style,** or any of the event handlers like onmouseover. It is extremely important that event handler attributes should follow Rule #3 for HTML JavaScript Data Values.

what is the reason that the complex attributes should not be escaped, (**This should not be used for complex attributes like href, src, style**) is this would create an ambiguity or break the values of the attributes?

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 4):

It isn't that they shouldn't be escaped, it is that escaping them is insufficient to make the data safe against XSS.

---

Escaping data stops it breaking out of the attribute and starting a new attribute or element.

That isn't enough if the attribute is one that can already execute JavaScript.

This is vulnerable to XSS:

```
$external_input = '"><script>alert("got you");</script>';
?><input class="<?php echo $external_input ?>">
```

But if you escape `$external_input` then the attribute value just becomes nonsense. It isn't harmful.

The following, on the other hand, allows arbitrary scripts to be executed even if the HTML is escaped.

```
$external_input = 'alert("got you");';
?><input onmouseover="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($external_input); ?>">
```

---

You need to ensure the data is safe for whatever data format the value is (and then you should still escape it).

Putting a value in an `href` attribute? Make sure it is a URL and the URL scheme is one you trust (like `http:` and not like `javascript:`).

Putting a value in a script? Escape it for the JS (which you'd generally use a JSON encoder for).

And so on.